# Numeric: Why multiply matrix lines by constants before solve linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, finite-differences

I'm learning about [Finite Difference Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method)(FDM) $(2)$ on Poisson equation $(1)$ and basically we do

$$
\nabla^2 u = f  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$
$$
\nabla^2 u \approx \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{h_x^2} & \dfrac{-2}{h_x^2} & \dfrac{1}{h_x^2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u_{i-1} \\ u_{i} \\ u_{i+1}\end{bmatrix}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
$$

Mixing $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $(3)\ \forall \ i=1, \ \cdots, n-2$ and get the system $(4)$ by adding the boundary conditions

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{h_x^2} & \dfrac{-2}{h_x^2} & \dfrac{1}{h_x^2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u_{i-1} \\ u_{i} \\ u_{i+1}\end{bmatrix} = f_i  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)
$$
$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & & & & \\ \frac{1}{h_x^2} & \frac{-2}{h_x^2} & \frac{1}{h_x^2} & & \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \\
& & \frac{1}{h_x^2} & \frac{-2}{h_x^2} & \frac{1}{h_x^2}  \\ 
& & & & 1 \end{bmatrix}}_{A} \begin{bmatrix}u_{0} \\ u_{1} \\ \vdots \\ u_{n-2} \\ u_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} u_a \\ f_1 \\ \vdots \\ f_{n-2} \\ u_{b}\end{bmatrix}  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)
$$

But I also can write $(4)$ as $(5)$ by multiplying the internal lines by $h_x^2$

$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & & & & \\ 1 & -2 & 1 & & \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \\
& & 1 & -2 & 1  \\ 
& & & & 1 \end{bmatrix}}_{B} \begin{bmatrix}u_{0} \\ u_{1} \\ \vdots \\ u_{n-2} \\ u_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} u_a \\ h_x^2f(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ h_x^2f(x_{n-2}) \\ u_{b}\end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (5)
$$

**Question:** Why $(5)$ is better than $(4)$ to solve numerically? It seems to be the same system, but could $\text{cond}(A) \ne \text{cond}(B)$? My question also applies to the $2D$ case in which someone told me the formulation $(7)$ is better than the formulation $(6)$.

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{h_x^2} & \dfrac{1}{h_y^2} & -2\left(\dfrac{1}{h_x^2}+\dfrac{1}{h_y^2}\right) & \dfrac{1}{h_y^2} &\dfrac{1}{h_x^2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u_{j,i-1} \\ u_{j-1,i} \\ u_{j,i} \\ u_{j+1,i} \\ u_{j,i+1}\end{bmatrix} = f_{j,i} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (6)
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{h_y}{h_x} & \dfrac{h_x}{h_y} & -2\left(\dfrac{h_y}{h_x}+\dfrac{h_x}{h_y}\right) & \dfrac{h_x}{h_y} &\dfrac{1}{h_x^2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u_{j,i-1} \\ u_{j-1,i} \\ u_{j,i} \\ u_{j+1,i} \\ u_{j,i+1}\end{bmatrix} = h_x h_y \cdot f_{j,i} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (7)
$$

Comment: One matrix is just a scalar multiple of the other. What concerns the condition numbers, there's no difference between the two formulations. On the other hand, (5) and (7) look more elegant when written down on the paper and give the matrices a sort of an $h$-independent flavor.

Comment: It could make a difference where the residual is used in some (heuristic) control without accounting for the scales of the components. In this context I can only think of line-search methods.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel The condition number is not the same. I took a numerical example with $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2000 & 1000\end{bmatrix}$ and $C=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2& 1\end{bmatrix}$ and I got $\kappa(A) = 5000/3$ and $\kappa(C) = 3$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann In fact, while computing the residual (for iterative methods), some values in the vector $\mathbf{u}$ are more sensible than others.

Comment: Yes, and rescaling by weights during the collection of the residual into a single number is effectively the same as applying a diagonal pre-conditioner to the system. Or one could use a weighted vector norm to get the same effect in the corresponding condition number. So this pre-multiplication removes a quasi-artificial worsening of the condition number that has no (or nearly so) effect on the actual numerical solution of the system.

Comment: This is something else. Your $A$ and $C$ are obviously not results of scaling by a scalar.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel It's the main question: I asked about multiplying only lines, not all the matrix.